# Can I make ReText use a different font type for displaying code?

Tags: configuration, fonts, qt

I'm using ReText 3.1.4 (Lubuntu 12.10) to make notes for myself. I want to know if it's possible to use a different font for displaying text that is marked as code in **preview mode**:

[image: ReText preview]

In the image, `Sort` and `~/.config/pcmanfm/lubuntu/desktop-items-0.conf` appear *faded*. I feel that's an issue with Courier (not just in ReText). I would like to use Ubuntu Mono or DejaVu Sans Mono instead of Courier. Is that possible? How?

I installed all the recommended software suggested at the time of installing Retext from the Lubuntu Software Center and that included `Qt Configuration 4.8.3` which allows a lot of customization. I can use the Fonts tab of this application to change the default font but not that of the font responsible for text in depicting code:

[image: ReText preview with different default font]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) to achieve this.

If you are new to CSS and want some help/tutorial, see this Stack Overflow question:

- [image: SO Favicon] [The best CSS tutorial/site/blog/book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book)

Also refer to the ReText Wiki for Configuration File:

- [image: ReText Favicon] [ReText Wiki for Configuration File](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/wiki/Configuration%20file/)

Follow these steps to create and modify the CSS File:

1. ReText stores its configuration files at `~/.config/ReText project/ReText.conf`. Open your File Manager (Nautilus if you are using Ubuntu). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show all the hidden files. Now, navigate to the directory `.config` → `ReText project`. Here you would find `ReText.conf`. We would need to edit it to point to our `css` file. But let's first create the `css` file.
2. In this same directory create a file called `myconfig.css` (you can name it whatever you want). Now open it in a Text Editor.
3. Edit the file as below:

   ```css
   code {
       font-family: Ubuntu Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono;
       background-color: #D3D3D3;
   }

   pre {
       background-color: #D3D3D3;
   }
   ```

   Obviously, what you want is to only set the `font-family` property to `code` tag. However, I recommend to set `background-color` property as well to both `code` and `pre` tags. I have set the `background-color` to `LightGrey` (its Hex Value is `#D3D3D3`). You may modify the color to your tastes and preferences. The following link should help you in this regard.

   - [image: W3Schools Favicon] [Popular Colors and their Hex Values](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colorsfull.asp)
4. Now modify ReText's Configuration file to point it to the newly created stylesheet. Open `~/.config/ReText project/ReText.conf` in your Text Editor and add the `styleSheet` setting at the end and point it to its location. For me it is:

   ```
   styleSheet=/home/aditya/.config/ReText project/myconfig.css
   ```

   [image: ReText Conf File]

   **Note:**

   - Ensure that you provide the full path to the file. It cannot expand `~` as your `$HOME`.
   - Furthermore, if you named your css file as something other than `myconfig.css` or placed it in some other directory, ensure that you provide the correct file name and path.
5. If you already had ReText running, close and restart it again for changes to take effect.

[image: mission accomplished]

---

### How to know what HTML `<tag>` to modify

If you are unsure about the tag names, you can view the HTML code of your markdown and then make your preferred changes to CSS.

*Edit* Menu → *View HTML code* would show the markup of your markdown text.

[image: know the tags]